# What are the available precision of system clock for Java 8 and 11 in each platform (windows, macOS, Linux)?

Tags: java-time

I'm aware that Java 8 (Oracle) system `Clock` implementation is limited to milliseconds at most, and that Java 9+ fixed that so in principle could get up to nanoseconds from the underlying clock. But then the underlying clock resolution may be ticking in steps of 1000ns or 100ns or 10ms, etc.

I know that in macOS Mojave the Java 8 clock give me resolution of 1ms and with Java 11 the resolution is 1ns

```
System.out.println(Instant.now()); // macOS Mojave Java 8 : 2019-11-15T09:04:32.714Z
System.out.println(Instant.now()); // macOS Mojave Java 11: 2019-11-15T09:01:30.867915Z
```

Is there a list of the actual precision / accuracy / resolutions per Java platform and OS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Java 8

Up to milliseconds

**Windows 10**:

**Linux 2.4**: 10 ms (if I interpret right time(7))

**Linux 2.6**:

**macOS Mojave**:  1ms resolution

## Java 11

**Windows 10**:

**Linux 2.4**:

**Linux 2.6**:

**macOS Mojave**: 1ns resolution